# openssl s_client hangs

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I am trying to look at some ssl certs with openssl's s_client. For some reason it hangs with the connection open after spitting out the cert info.

Here is the command I am using and the output:

```
mike@sleepycat:~☺  openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 O = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3, OU = www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Palo Alto/O=Facebook, Inc./CN=www.facebook.com
   i:/O=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3/OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign
 1 s:/O=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3/OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Palo Alto/O=Facebook, Inc./CN=www.facebook.com
issuer=/O=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3/OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2230 bytes and written 388 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 5FFDA57069D60A3FBEBCC667B76B8CDF649DA6D04656985D828DE2AE74426645
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: FA27B6E7A08420EE27F74A01136077C064891D49BA64BE508CD99242F52A482AC6AA44D7D4487A99728C04F2EA547352
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 86000 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 9d da 29 68 1c 35 19 21-da 2a 45 eb 17 71 83 42   ..)h.5.!.*E..q.B
    0010 - 6d 5c 55 97 82 18 36 9a-b6 7d 10 2c 25 2f 31 43   m\U...6..}.,%/1C
    0020 - 57 77 d1 f1 bf 30 26 a8-84 90 d1 6c 91 83 72 7d   Ww...0&....l..r}
    0030 - 33 e6 a5 bf e3 82 d4 00-8d 44 c8 8a 03 71 58 6c   3........D...qXl
    0040 - 28 f4 41 b4 71 67 6c e6-06 39 06 d5 3c 0d ed de   (.A.qgl..9..<...
    0050 - ba e9 48 2c fe d5 6e a0-a4 cf 27 92 1b 96 79 dc   ..H,..n...'...y.
    0060 - 9a d8 3c 6e 04 f0 2d 7c-05 d4 7b d5 8a a6 99 76   ..<n..-|..{....v
    0070 - c3 57 11 3e 7c 0a 9d 46-a2 01 b9 a7 8a ce 5b 32   .W.>|..F......[2
    0080 - 8e 40 30 f3 14 93 b4 e4-55 e0 9c e8 dc 2f 02 a8   .@0.....U..../..
    0090 - ef d9 52 54 d2 16 f9 8d-23 e1 34 14 26 64 29 c8   ..RT....#.4.&d).
    00a0 - c8 0a 09 97 24 eb 6c 92-ff 82 f5 e8 a1 6f 2a f2   ....$.l......o*.

    Start Time: 1347376514
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

And this is where is stays without ever completing. How can I get this command to complete cleanly so I can use it in a script? I am running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's waiting for your HTTP command,

simply a `GET /` and press enter would be good.

Comment: You are amazing. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

For fully automated solution, you can use `echo -n`:

`echo -n | openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443`

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a HEAD request with OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -quiet -connect github.com:443 <<eof
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Host: github.com

eof
```

Note that you can also use "HTTP/2", but be careful because some servers
(e.g. github.com) do not support it.